# Copy files from GCP project to Google Cloud VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have uploaded files to Google project in my home directory :

[image: Files in my directory]

I have an instance called sentiment-instance-1

I want to copy the file sentiment_insights.zip from google project social-media-analysis-199517 to my instance

```
root@sentiment-instance-1:/home/amiteshkesinha#
```

Have tried to use the following command but got error

```
amiteshkesinha@social-media-analysis-199517:~$ gsutil cp amiteshkesinha@social-media-analysis-199517>:/home/amiteshkesinha/sentiment_insights.zip root@sentiment-instance-1>:/home/amiteshkesinha
```

[image: Output after running this command]

How to copy this file. I am new with GCP and unable to find a way out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using Google Cloud SDK Shell. There after writing the following command, the files got updated.

```
gcloud compute scp D:/projects/Amitesh/sentiment_insights.zip --zone=us-east1-b root@sentiment-instance-1:/home/amiteshkesinha/
```